# Generic Update method that avoids mass assignment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-entities

How do I create a **generic** update method in my generic repository that avoids the mass assignment problem by specifying which properties to update?

Currently I have separate update methods for each of my 'non-generic' repositories, where i create a new entity based on id, then manually assign each property.  See code below for example.

```
    public OperationStatus DoUpdateGame(Game game)
    {
        var gm = DataContext.Games.Where(g => g.Id == game.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (gm != null)
        {
            //manually map all properties to avoid mass assignment security issues
            gm.CreatorId = game.CreatorId;
            gm.CurrentOrderPosition = game.CurrentOrderPosition;
            gm.HasStarted = game.HasStarted;
            gm.Name = game.Name;
            gm.HasEnded = game.HasEnded;
            gm.WinnerId = game.WinnerId;
        }
        return new OperationStatus { Status = true };
    }
```

I want to get rid of the duplication (separate update methods for each repository) & have a single update method in my generic repository.  To make this generic, I need to

1. Know how to create a new, generic entity 'copy'
2. Use a list of strings to mark which properties to update

I'm trying to do something like this (currently doesn't work).  Guidance appreciated!

```
public virtual OperationStatus Update(T entity, string idColName, params string[] propsToUpdate) 
    {
        OperationStatus opStatus = new OperationStatus { Status = true };

        // this line fails with 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
        var current = DataContext.Set<T>().Where(g => g.GetType().GetProperty(idColName) == entity.GetType().GetProperty(idColName)).FirstOrDefault();

        try
        {
            if (propsToUpdate != null && propsToUpdate.Length > 0)
            {
                //update specific properties
                foreach (var propName in propsToUpdate)
                {
                    TrySetProperty(current, propName, entity.GetType().GetProperty(propName));
                }
            }

            opStatus.Status = true; // DataContext.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            // log
        }

        return opStatus;
    }

    private void TrySetProperty(object obj, string property, object value)
    {
        var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
            prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I'm now tyring to use automapper with a DTO object to map the original entity to the DTO.  Am now getting a 'no items in sequence error'... code below

```
public virtual OperationStatus Update(T entity, string idColName, params string[] propsToUpdate) 
    {
        OperationStatus opStatus = new OperationStatus { Status = true };

        var sourceType = entity.GetType();

        // this line gives the 'no items in sequence error
        var destinationType = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().
          Where(map => map.SourceType == sourceType).
          Single().DestinationType;

        var current = Mapper.Map(entity, destinationType);
```

My automapperconfiguration

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ConfigureMapping();
    }

    private static void ConfigureMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Game, GameUpdateDTO>();
    }
}
```

Line in global.asax

```
            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

DTO model

```
 class GameUpdateDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CurrentOrderPosition { get; set; }
    public bool HasStarted { get; set; }
    public bool HasEnded { get; set; }
    public int WinnerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are `game` and `gm` the same type (`Game`)? If so.. you should think about introducing a "view model" in between the two. Then the task becomes trivial with a library like Automapper or ValueInjecter.

Comment: Yes, they are - how would i use automapper with generic type though?

Comment: Simply: `entity = Mapper.Map(current, entity);`. Type inference does the rest.

Comment: Make sure you test what I said above though.. the parameters might be the other way around in the call to `Map` (can't remember off the top of my head).

Comment: i'm sorry I still don't follow - in your recent comment, what gives current it's value?  where do i set automapper to map entity to entityDTO (for example)??

Comment: I used your variable names from your code. You setup your maps using CreateMap once at application startup. I am still unsure if you are going to introduce a Dto in this scenario. If you are, I can explain further.

Comment: Yes - using DTOs for all my models would allow me to exclude potential properties, for example 'IsAdmin' (I know this isn't in my example).

Comment: Ok, have used automapper with DTO & Slauma's answer below and have now got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a DTO class there is an easy way for a generic update that is built in into Entity Framework:

```
public void Update<T>(object dto, Expression<Func<T, bool>> currentEntityFilter)
    where T : class
{
    var current = DataContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(currentEntityFilter);
    DataContext.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(dto);
}
```

It's important that the DTO properties have the same names as the entity properties.

You can call it like so:

```
Update<Game>(gameUpdateDto, g => g.Id == gameUpdateDto.Id);
```

Or if you just want to update a few selected properties, like so:

```
Update<Game>(new
{
    gameUpdateDto.Name,
    gameUpdateDto.HasStarted,
    gameUpdateDto.HasEnded
}, g => g.Id == gameUpdateDto.Id);
```

If you always want to update an entity by its key I would prefer this signature and implementation:

```
public void Update<T>(object dto, params object[] keyValues)
    where T : class
{
    var current = DataContext.Set<T>().Find(keyValues);
    DataContext.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(dto);
}
```

To be called like so:

```
Update<Game>(gameUpdateDto, gameUpdateDto.Id);
```

Note that this does not work if you want to update an entity including its navigation properties to related entities.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks, used this with automapper & works a dream.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper) to solve this issue very easily. Here are some code that might give you some idea. I find the link very helpful. You might want to have a look there.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Game, Game>();
Mapper.DynamicMap(newGame, oldGame);
GameRepository.Update(oldGame);
```

**Update**
Try this example for generic type

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var customerRepo = new Repository<Customer>(new Customer());
            var userRepo = new Repository<User>(new User());

            customerRepo.Update(new Customer
                                    {
                                        DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
                                        FirstName = "Customer",
                                        LastName = "Cust",
                                        NumberOfOrders = 3
                                    });
            userRepo.Update(new User
                                {
                                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
                                    FirstName = "User",
                                    LastName = "Us"
                                });
            userRepo.Show();
            customerRepo.Show();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public class Repository<T>
        {
            private T _entity;

            public Repository(T entity)
            {
                _entity = entity;
            }

            public void Update(T data)
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<T, T>();
                Mapper.DynamicMap(data, _entity);
            }

            public void Show()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_entity.ToString());
            }
        }

        public class Customer
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

            public int NumberOfOrders { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return GetType().Name + "= " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + DateOfBirth + " " + NumberOfOrders;
            }
        }

        public class User
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return GetType().Name + "= " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + DateOfBirth;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would i use automapper with generic type though?

Comment: thanks for the udpate  -i still don't follow though sorry - here you are just mapping Customer to Customer - where are the specific properties being selected/restricted?